# TypeError: server.connection is not a function in Hapi nodejs

Tags: node.js, hapi.js

I started working with Hapi nodejs framework. I am using "hapi@17.2.0" and here is my code in server.js to initiate application.

```
'use strict';

const Hapi = require('hapi');

const server = new Hapi.Server();
server.connection({ port: 3000, host: 'localhost' });

server.route({
    method: 'GET',
    path: '/',
    handler: function (request, reply) {
        reply('Hello, world!');
    }
});

server.start((err) => {

    if (err) {
        throw err;
    }
    console.log(`Server running at: ${server.info.uri}`);
});
```

After running my project with `node server.js` from terminal it's throwing error as given below.

```
/var/www/html/hello_hapi/server.js:6
server.connection({ port: 3000, host: 'localhost' });
       ^

TypeError: server.connection is not a function
    at Object.<anonymous> (/var/www/html/hello_hapi/server.js:6:8)
    at Module._compile (module.js:612:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:623:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:531:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:494:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:486:3)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:653:10)
    at startup (bootstrap_node.js:187:16)
    at bootstrap_node.js:608:3
```

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I found a solution to resolve my error. I just replaced
`server.connection({ port: 3000, host: 'localhost' });`
with
`const server = new Hapi.Server({ port: 3000, host: 'localhost' });`

Here is the description below:
According to hapi v17.0.0 they Removed support for multiple connections for a single server

1. The server.connection() method is replaced with options passed directly when creating a server object.
2. connection property is removed from all objects.
3. All connection methods moved to the server.
4. Removed support for labels and select() methods and options.

Comment: You are correct that v17 does not support multiple connections on a server any more, glad you figured it out!

Answer (score 1):

In hapi 16, there was support for server.connection(), but in hapi 17, they replaced server.connection() and instead

```
const Hapi = require('hapi')
const server = Hapi.server({
port:3000 || process.env.port
})
```

This can be used in node js.

If you are using typescript and typings, then

```
const server = new Hapi.server({port:3000 || process.env.port})
```

Answer (score 1):

replace with this

```
const server = new Hapi.Server({  
  host: 'localhost',
  port: 3000
})
```

if you are using this

```
server.connection({   

    port: 8000,
    host: 'localhost'

});
```